# Get alert when external JavaScript is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am loading a script from the google plus button only when the user requests it. The code that is used is the following:

```
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
```

When I fire this script it will change the placeholder into the google plus button. The placeholder looks like this:

```
<g:plusone size="tall" annotation="none"></g:plusone>
```

There are a few other buttons I load like this, only when needed.

Now sometimes the buttons take a while to load. Is there a way get an alert when all the buttons are loaded.

I can then just display a loader until it is fully loaded, and then display it nicely.

I use jQuery as my javascript framework.

## Edit

For a better solution check out this question: [Invoking handler when all scripts finished loading via $.getScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028724/invoking-handler-when-all-scripts-finished-loading-via-getscript/8131608#8131608)

A better way to go is using [jQueries deffered object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). I added a small example and fiddle to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery provides a mechanism to define a script load handler:

```
$.getScript( 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js', function () {
    // the script has loaded and executed
});
```

This handler is invoked *after* the script has executed, so it should suit your needs...

Comment: Ah yes this was the function I was searching for. Do you know if this works also for multiple files. Only fire the function when all the scripts are done loading.

Comment: @Saif: It might return a deferred object which you can then use together with `$.when`.

Comment: @SaifBechan I've opened [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028724/invoking-handler-when-all-scripts-finished-loading-via-getscript) to address the issue...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the feature without modifying existing content, use the code below:

```
(function(){
    var poller = window.setInterval(function(){//Set poller
        if($('g\\:plusone').length == 0){      // When the document doesn't have
            clearInterval(poller);             // any g:plusone elements, clear
                                               // poller, and execute your code
            //Run your code..
        }
    }, 200);  //Checks at a frequence of 200ms
})();
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I guess this will work for multiple elements also. I can just add a unique class to all the elements, and when they are all filles I can clear the poller. I will check this out.