# Invoking handler when all scripts finished loading via $.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So let's say we load a bunch of scripts via `$.getScript`:

```
$.getScript( 'js/script1.js' );
$.getScript( 'js/script2.js' );
$.getScript( 'js/script3.js' );
```

Now, I'd like to invoke a handler when all those scripts finished loading. I tried binding a handler for the global [`ajaxStop` event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/). According to [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events), the `ajaxStop` global event is triggered if there are no more Ajax requests being processed.

```
$( document ).ajaxStop( handler );
```

but it doesn't work (the handler is not invoked).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/etGPc/2/

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried combining the promises with `$.when()`?  (Or however it is that one does that ...)

Comment: @Pointy No, I have yet to learn how to use deferreds in jQuery. For now, I would like to understand why `.ajaxStop()` fails - I must be using it wrong or something...

Comment: Well I don't know; I've never tried to use it.  I'll see if I can make the promise thing work in your fiddle. (One slightly odd thing is that the "ajaxStop" event is triggered differently than the others, in the jQuery source code.)

Comment: It worked in 1.2.6 http://jsfiddle.net/etGPc/4/.

Comment: getScript won't fire an `ajaxStart`-event and therefor also won't fire an `ajaxStop`-event. If you add a `$.get(...)` call you will see your stop-handler be triggered as expected. But I have no idea, why `fireGlobals` in line [7336](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.6.4/jQuery.ajax#L7336) will be false when getScript is used compared to a `$.get(...)` ...

Comment: @john_doe: Perhaps that's because of the `ajaxPrefilter` with `scripts` which are cross-domain (the scenario here) - see https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js#L20.

Comment: @Pointy Using `$.when().then()` is super-easy. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/etGPc/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're doing it wrong anyways :)

here is one of the things that can happen: 
imagine the scripts are cached, then they might be loaded in no time. 
so, straight after the first call `$.getScript( 'js/script1.js' );` the script will be available and $.ajaxStop (might!!!) get called, in the worst case that would happen three times.

to answer your question indirectly i would propose a different solution which avoids this race condition alltogether. 
you can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/etGPc/8/

```
var urls, log, loaded;

// urls to load
urls = [
    'https://raw.github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/js/script.js',
    'https://raw.github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/js/plugins.js',
    'https://raw.github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js'
];

// urls loaded 
loaded = []; 


log = $( '#log' ); 

$.map( urls, function( url ){
    $.getScript( url, function(){
        // append to loaded urls
        loaded.push( url ); 
        log.append( "loaded " + url + "<br>" ); 

        // all loaded now? 
        if( loaded.length == urls.length ){
            log.append( "<b>all done!</b>" ); 
        }
    } ); 
} );
```

if you haven't seen `jQuery.map` before: it's not really different from a for-loop :)

another advantage here is that this method doesn't get confused if you have other ajax requests going on at the same time.

p.s. to avoid naming-clashes you can wrap the entire thing in a self-executing function, i.e.

```
function(){
    var urls, log, loaded; 

    ... all code here ... 
} ();
```

---

**Update:** Refactored the code a bit...

```
var urls, loadedUrls, log;

urls = [
    'https://raw.github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/js/script.js',
    'https://raw.github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/js/plugins.js',
    'https://raw.github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js'
];    

loadedUrls = [];

log = $( '#log' )[0];

urls.forEach(function ( url ) {
    $.getScript( url, function () {
        loadedUrls.push( url );

        $( log ).append( 'loaded ' + url + '<br>' );

        if( loadedUrls.length === urls.length ){
            $( log ).append( '<b>all done!</b>' );
        }
    });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/etGPc/10/

Comment: @kritzikratzi Yes, having a second array is a good solution. You don't need `$.map` though - invoking `forEach` on the `urls` array is sufficient.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas that's correct, i write lots of mathematica code where map and foreach are basically the same...

Comment: @kritzikratzi Well, `each`/`forEach` is the general iterator mechanism, whereas `map` specializes in replacing the values of the array.

Answer (score 3):

I digged a little more into this issue and it's indeed the cross-domain script request that's the caveat. As I posted in the comments, that scenario has been implemented such that it sets the `global` option to `false`. This makes jQuery not to fire global ajax events. (No idea *why* that has been implemented though.)

This can be confirmed with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etGPc/7/) (pass means `ajaxStop` is fired):

- cross-domain, no script: pass
- cross domain, script: **fail**
- no cross-domain, no script: pass
- no cross-domain, script: pass

The most straight-forward thing to do is simply adding another prefilter which forces the `global` option to true:

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter( "script", function() {
    s.global = true;
});
```

This also makes this failing scenario pass in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this `:)`

Answer (score 2):

While dealing with my own problem I found a much better and elegant solution to this problem, and it is using the [jQuery deffered object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). I think you already know about the function, maybe for another usecase, but it works great for loading files, and fire functions when eveything is done. Code is as follows:

```
function getLatestNews() {
    return $.get('/echo/js/?delay=2&js=', function(data) {
        console.log('news data received');
        $('.news').css({'color':'blue'});
    });
}

function getLatestReactions() {
    return $.get('/echo/js/?delay=5&js=', function(data) {
        console.log('reactions data received');
        $('.reactions').css({'color':'green'});
    });
}

function prepareInterface() {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        var latest = $('.news, .reactions');
        latest.slideDown(500, dfd.resolve);
        latest.addClass('active');
    }).promise();
}

$.when(
    getLatestNews(), 
    getLatestReactions(), 
    prepareInterface()
).then(function() {
    console.log('fire after requests succeed');
    $('.finished').html('I am done!');
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('something went wrong!');
});
```

I made a small fiddle where you can check out the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/saifbechan/BKTwT/

You can check out a running copy there, I took the snippet from this tutorial, it's worth reading the whole tutorial, lot's of good information on asynchronous ajax.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg723713

Comment: Yes, the `$.when().then()` patterns is cool `:)` I've already made a solution with this pattern (see my last comment to my question above).

Comment: Oh I did not see that, it was hidden.

Comment: ah, i love this pattern! great solution.